# Programmatically create MS SQL Compact database file on a desktop

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows-mobile, compact-database

Is it possible to create an SDF database file for MS SQL Server Compact on a desktop.?

I want to craete a desktop application which can create an SDF database file for copying it to a Windows Mobile device.

Is it possible and how?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. to quote from [the MSDN page on SqlCeEngine.CreateDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa237899%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
if (File.Exists("Test.sdf"))
File.Delete("Test.sdf");

string connStr = "Data Source = Test.sdf; Password = <password>;";

SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
engine.CreateDatabase();
engine.Dispose();
SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try 
{
   conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
   conn.Open();

   SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE myTable (col1 int, col2 ntext)";
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

catch {}

finally 
{
   conn.Close();
}
```

After this, you can just copy Test.sdf onto the mobile device.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create how?

From Visual Studio?  Open the Server Explorer and add a new Data Connection.  Select SQL Compact as the data source, give it a file name and click Create.

From Code? Use the SqlCeEngine class.  Give it a connection string and call Create.